# The Spark union is heavy

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

```
val billRDD = sc.textFile("file/cdr/*/2018/07/27/20/*").map(line => line.split("\\|"))
val areaCodeAll: RDD[((String, String, String), List[List[String]])] = billRDD.repartition(24).map(x=>((x(76),x(77),x(78)),List(x(3),x(53),x(54),x(20),x(44),x(61),x(62),x(22),x(63),x(24),x(64),x(65),x(47),x(48),x(60),x(68),x(67))))
  .combineByKey(
    (v: List[String]) => List(v),
    (c:List[List[String]],v:List[String]) => v +: c,
    (c1:List[List[String]],c2:List[List[String]]) => List.concat(c1,c2)
  )
areaCodeAll.cache()
val provinceAll = areaCodeAll.map(x => (x._1._1,x._2)).filter(_._1!="-1").reduceByKey(_:::_)
val cityAll = areaCodeAll.map(x => (x._1._2,x._2)).filter(_._1!="-1").reduceByKey(_:::_)
val countyAll = areaCodeAll.map(x => (x._1._3,x._2)).filter(_._1!="-1")
val dataByAreaCode = provinceAll.union(cityAll).union(countyAll)
```

My source file number is 48，size is 871.5M.This is info of files:

[image]

This is my spark-shell settings:

```
spark-shell --master yarn-client spark.default.parallelism=600 --conf spark.rdd.compress=true  --queue=queue_qoezy --num-executors 48 --executor-cores 4 --executor-memory 16g --driver-memory 8g --conf spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer
```

Actually,running time of this program is very long，up to 5 min。
This is DAG Visualization from Spark web UI:
[image]

The program is always stuck at the last task:
[image]

How to  optimize my spark program by scala？
Help and thanks!

Answer (score 0):

from what I see , Im pretty sure the task that takes most time for you is actually the reduceByKey and not the union and that makes sense because Its a shuffle ( if you dont know how shuffle works ask me in the comments). you can see the reduce action is set in stage 8.
as far as I know union should be really quick at least when compared to reduce.

P.S. if you have enough executors you should look into treeReduce.